# How do you convert between 12 hour time and 24 hour time in PHP?

Tags: php, string, time, formatting, date-conversion

I have a time as a string, for example:

```
$time = '5:36 pm';
```

I require this to be in 24 hour format (i.e. `17:36`), however I don't know which functions I need to use to convert it.

Comment: Post your code please. However: `date('H:i' [, $timestamp])`. Check http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: It's a real question, I just searched Google with almost exactly the same question myself, and it's reasonable not to have any code for something this simple as you might not know where to start. The proof that it's a real question is how many upvotes the answer has.

Comment: I edited this question to show a **bit** more code and I'm voting to reopen it because it's an old question, many others are duplicates of this one, it appears in the top positions for related searches, and it actually has an answer, so it *is* a real question in my opinion.

Answer (score 199, accepted):

```
// 24-hour time to 12-hour time 
$time_in_12_hour_format  = date("g:i a", strtotime("13:30"));
output: 1:30 pm

// 12-hour time to 24-hour time 
$time_in_24_hour_format  = date("H:i", strtotime("1:30 PM"));
output: 13:30
```

Comment: The second line should specify if the input time is AM or PM, right?

Comment: echo $wantedtime = $_POST['time_hour'].":".$_POST['time_minute']." ".$_POST['time_meridian']."<br/>";
echo $g = date("H:i");
echo "<br/>";
echo $time_in_24_hour_format  = date("H:i", strtotime("$wantedtime"));
$time_in_24_hour_format = explode(":",time_in_24_hour_format);
exit(0);

Comment: date("H:i", strtotime("0:00 AM")); gives output as 05:30 is this correct?

Comment: "a" is important

Comment: echo date("g:i a", strtotime($result['hourOpeningHour'])) is this right for variable from database.

Answer (score 0):

If the incoming time expression format is known in advance, DateTime class methods can be used.

- `g` : hour from 1 - 12 without leading zeros
- `H` : hour from 00 - 23 with leading zeros
- `i` : minutes from 00 - 59 with leading zeros
- `a` : `am` or `pm`

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/MrYgA))

```
$time12 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', '13:30')->format("g:i a");
echo $time12;

echo "\n---\n";

$time24 = DateTime::createFromFormat('g:i a', '1:30 pm')->format("H:i");
echo $time24;
```

Output:

```
1:30 pm
---
13:30
```