# Change time from 12 PM to 12:00 and insert into sql table

Tags: php, mysql

I've recently updated my database structure and i currently have about 500 records in my database, and inserting a record one by one manually is going to be extremely time consuming.

At the moment i have a table called `brunches` which has the following columns

`brunchid` `timemonday` `timetuesday` `timewednesday` `timethursday` `timefriday` `timesaturday` `timesunday`

Currently each column would have a time that the brunch operates but is in the following format '11 AM - 4 PM'

i've created a new table called schedule which has the following columns

```
brunchid,
mondaystart,
mondayfinish,
tuesdaystart,
tuesdayfinish,
wednesdaystart,
wednesdayfinish,
thursdaystart,
thursdayfinish,
fridaystart,
fridayfinish,
saturdaystart,
saturdayfinish,
sundaystart,
sundayfinish
```

and the format of that is now 12:00

i am wondering the best way to get the data from each column and convert it from 11 AM - 4PM and changing that automatically to 11:00 AM - 16:00

and then inserting it into the database table `schedule`

what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you convert between 12 hour time and 24 hour time in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742191/how-do-you-convert-between-12-hour-time-and-24-hour-time-in-php)

Comment: _"to 11:00 AM - 16:00"_ - Don't  you mean just _"to 11:00 - 16:00"_? Otherwise you would be mixing 24h and 12h formats, which would be really confusing.

Comment: Storing `11 AM - 4PM` in a single column is a general bad idea, because it means that the start and end times are not normalized.  Instead, have separate columns for the two points in the date/time range.

Comment: If you made those fields into TIME datatypes and stored a sensible time you would make so many bits of your life easier in the coming days

Answer (score 0):

You can do this while inserting into Schedule table

```
    SELECT STR_TO_DATE( '11:00 PM', '%l:%i %p' )
```

Output

```
    23:00:00
```