# Convert 12hr format to 24 hour format i PHP

Tags: php, date

I am working on a project and i get dates from my IMAP client using imap_headerinfo(). I get 2021 24 02 01:44 when I want it to be 2021 24 02 13:44 aka. 24  hours format. How to I convert this?

code:

```
$header = imap_headerinfo($imap, $result[$i]);

$date = $header->date;
```

Comment: How are you gonna determine valid time without AM/PM ?

Comment: Im Norwegian, we usually use 24 hour format.

Comment: That's not what the question was about. It was about how you differ `01:44` you get from IMAP. How do you know when it's `13:44` and when it's actually `01:44` if it doesn't include AM/PM?

Comment: I'm Polish, we also use 24h which is the best as we can see... however, how do you know that 01:44 is 01:44 or 13:44? without AM/PM part?
converting is quite simple if you have this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8742253/1066240

Comment: Ok, I get it. But I would think te imap response has a clue what exact time it is... It does not show AM or PM... im thinking there is some settings to get the 24 hour format.

Comment: Use `udate` which has the Unix timestamp. Then you can convert it to whichever format your heart desires.

Comment: Setting time format in 24h or Unix type, would be best option. Otherwise there's no way to guess.

Comment: Yes, please provide code or link to set the header to 24h format. =) Didn't find anything on it.

Comment: as mentioned by @el-vanja, you can use $header->udate instead of $header->date to retrieve message date in Unix time.

Comment: Ok, but udate shows only 1970 01 01 01:00 on webpage? Something more needed?